# Sensor de movimento

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

Como faço para identificar o movimento de rotação do iPhone no seu próprio eixo (mesma rotação que um pião)? Consegui identificar praticamente todas as rotações possíveis e não consegui identificar esta, que é justamente a que preciso para um jogo que estou desenvolvendo. O iPhone ficará em posição retrato.

**Mais precisamente preciso pegar a rotação em Y**

Comment: Acho que [isso aqui](http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/) pode te ajudar, utilizando o framework `CoreMotion`.

Comment: Infelizmente foi seguindo isso que consegui os outros porém não consegui implementar o Y, o que preciso basicamente é fazer algo semelhante ao exemplo do Quizzer

Comment: Para que você precisa de rotacionar o proprio eixo?

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar os valores, pode utilizar 3 formas, e aqui estão elas:

Declare

```
let motionKit = MotionKit()
```

E assim obtenha os dados das seguintes formas:

Dados do acelerômetro:

```
motionKit.getAccelerometerValues(interval: 1.0){
        (x, y, z) in
        //Do whatever you want with the x, y and z values
        println("X: \(x) Y: \(y) Z \(z)")
      }
```

Dados do giroscópio:

```
motionKit.getGyroValues(interval: 1.0){
        (x, y, z) in
        //Do whatever you want with the x, y and z values
        println("X: \(x) Y: \(y) Z \(z)")
     }
```

campo magnético em torno de seu dispositivo:

```
motionKit.getMagnetometerValues(interval: 1.0){
        (x, y, z) in
        //Do whatever you want with the x, y and z values
        println("X: \(x) Y: \(y) Z \(z)")
     }
```